# Javascript: toDataURL really slow, how to speed up?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have an animation that is being generating using Three.js and being piped out to a C++ application via websockets. I am grabbing each frame from the canvas, encoding it via base64 and then sending it out as a string. The problem is, the .toDataUrl() function I am calling is cutting my FPS in half from 60 to 30, does anyone know why this would have such a dramatic effect and if there's any other to get the canvas data? let me know if you need any more info.

Here's the HTML/JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js canvas - geometry - cube</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #f0f0f0;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>

        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var cube, plane;

            var targetRotation = 0;
            var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

            var mouseX = 0;
            var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            var ofSocket;


            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
                info.style.position = 'absolute';
                info.style.top = '10px';
                info.style.width = '100%';
                info.style.textAlign = 'center';
                info.innerHTML = 'Drag to spin the cube';
                container.appendChild( info );

                ofSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9093");

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
                camera.position.y = 150;
                camera.position.z = 500;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                // Cube

                var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );

                for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i += 2 ) {

                    var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
                    geometry.faces[ i ].color.setHex( hex );
                    geometry.faces[ i + 1 ].color.setHex( hex );

                }

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 } );

                cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                cube.position.y = 150;
                scene.add( cube );

                // Plane

                var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 200, 200 );
                geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

                var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xe0e0e0, overdraw: 0.5 } );

                plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                scene.add( plane );

                renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

                mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
                targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;

                targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.02;

            }

            function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

                document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseOut( event ) {

                document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
                document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false );

            }

            function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

                if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                    targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

                }

            }

            function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

                if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                    event.preventDefault();

                    mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                    targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + ( mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown ) * 0.05;

                }

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();
                var image = renderer.domElement.toDataURL("image/png"); 
                ofSocket.send(image.replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
            }

            function render() {

                plane.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y += ( targetRotation - cube.rotation.y ) * 0.05;
                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Said method requires reading the value of every pixel, encoding it in a new image, then base64 encoding it. Not a very fast operation, probably not much you can do about it, but you might try reading the pixel data directly.

Comment: If using firefox you could try [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob), if not you could also get the ArrayBuffer from the [ImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object returned by [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData). Do not know how much improvement it would make though

Comment: Any reason you are using CanvasRenderer and not WebGLRenderer? Do you have to have the renderer at the full screen resolution?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Deleted comment to avoid confusion